# Containers of same host cannot access each other

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a prometheus container and Grafana container running on same host each container is bind with different port. when I try to add a data source to Grafana container as prometheus container(${host_name}:9090), I get a no route to host.

Hitting the ${hostname}:9090 and ${hostname}:3000 works fine on the browser.

when Starting the container I used a network

`docker network create --driver bridge prometheus`

`docker run --network prometheus -d -v /vvs/prometheus/conf:/etc/prometheus/ -v /vvs/prometheus/data:/prometheus -u 90900:90900 -p 9090:9090 --name prometheus1 prom/prometheus:v2.14.0  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus`

`docker run --network prometheus -d -v /vvs/grafana:/var/lib/grafana -p 3000:3000 --name Grafana grafana/grafana`

`docker network inspect prometheus` shows both containers are part of the prometheus network.

performing a curl from within Grafana to reach prometheus({hostname}:9090) gives me no route to host and vice versa to Grafana from prometheus container

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What hostname are you using to connect to Prometheus?

Comment: try to restart both containers once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have several options -

1. Use `prometheus1` as the hostname. Since both containers are in same network, they should be able to communicate with each other by their names.
2. Use private/static IP address of the docker host machine in order to communicate with prometheus.
3. Use docker compose and call each other by their service names (preferred/recommended).

Comment: Thanks for response.
1. doesn't work. I have already given a try
2. Currently I am trying to use the hostname of the host machine to connect
3. I don't want to use docker compose.
@vivekyad4v